# Slow response times from IIS

Tags: jquery, asp.net, iis-7

Maybe this doesn't belong to stackoverflow (?)

I have a classic ASP.NET webforms site running on IIS7.
The problem is that response times on even static resources are horribly slow.
Serving a 250k css file takes 2+ seconds in some cases.

There is also a static textfile containing json data for testing purposes.
This file takes about 10-20ms to get if I request that file manually.
If the same file is requested from the webpage (JQuery ajax call) the same file takes 300ms to fetch , and according to firebug, its all server wait time.

Is it ASP.NET that does some funky stuff when the files are served? 
Any ideas what can cause this kind of odd behavior?

(running the same site locally in the vs.net devserver does not show the same problem)

[edit]
Some updates

The textfile has querystring params to avoid local cache. 
each time the query string param changes, it takes 300ms to load.
requesting the same file using the same params takes it down to 20ms (and both firebug and webinspector says the file is loaded over the net and not received from local cache)

What can cause this?

Static images also behave strangely even w/o any querystring params.
Images loaded by jquery takes 3-400 ms .. requesting the same images manually takes 20ms (w/o any cache)

Answer (score 3):

Start with this

[Enable HTTP Compression of Static Content (IIS 7)](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc754668%28v=ws.10%29.aspx)

[Tuning IIS 7 for static content](http://www.ckode.dk/server-configuration/tuning-iis-7-for-static-content/)